# Timestamp of frame processing using peopleDetect

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, video-processing, frame-rate

I am using `peopleDetect` function to detect human object from video. I got the score from the `peopleDetect` method but now I need the time at which each frame was processed by `peopleDetect` function, because I need to plot time vs. score. The following code returns the score for each frame:

```
frameLeft = readerLeft.step();

% Detect people.
[bboxes,scores] = step(peopleDetector, frameLeft);

if ~isempty(bboxes)
    % Find the centroids of detected people.
    centroids = [round(bboxes(:, 1) + bboxes(:, 3) / 2), ...
        round(bboxes(:, 2) + bboxes(:, 4) / 2)];

    dispFrame = insertObjectAnnotation(frameLeft, 'rectangle' ,bboxes,scores);
else
    dispFrame = frameLeft;
end

% Display the frame.
step(player, dispFrame);
```

Question: how can I edit it to get time at each step as well?

Comment: @mikkola - That was very nice of you to place the post from MATLAB Central in this post for us to read... but you shouldn't have had to.  The OP telling us to go to an off-site resource to figure out what the problem is... is just being lazy. The OP has shown no effort, so you shouldn't have to fix that laziness. It should have been voted to close IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after you detected people, just save the time by using the `now` command.

I assume you have detected people at:

```
% Detect people.
[bboxes,scores] = step(peopleDetector, frameLeft);

if ~isempty(bboxes)
...
```

So then just add the time as:

```
% Detect people.
[bboxes,scores] = step(peopleDetector, frameLeft);

if ~isempty(bboxes)
timeStamps(idx) = now;
idx = idx + 1;
...
```

You initiate the `timeStamps` array in the beginning to speed it up. Also, of course initiate `idx = 1;` in the beginning

Comment: It returns the current time of system i think, I need the time of video, Like if there are 25 frames being processed from a video i need time at which each frame is processed in video.

Comment: Oh I see. Is there a time stamp available for each frame? If so, can't you just save the time of the frame? Or if you know the start time of the video and the frame rate, you can calculate the time stamp for each frame.

Comment: This is what i need to know if time stamp is available for each frame. I have videoFrameRate i.e. 25.

Comment: Ok. I don't know if you have time stamps embedded in the video information. But if not. Perhaps you can choose a start time i.e. when the video file was created or whatever seems legit. And then calculate the time stamps for each frame.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have used the total duration of video and number of total frames in video to calculate the time of each frame.